# How to intent from activity to fragment picture ( android studio)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

Hi i am in a trouble sending intent activity data to fragment .

I want to intent image(uri) activity to fragment.

I used activity class and .java/fragment like this

[image]

I used intent but it didn't work in fragment.

so i found a lot of example and i used bundle but It doesn't work.

It is activity code

```
 private void nextpageintent(String photoUri){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,picture.class);
    //intent.putExtra("photo", photoUri);
    startActivity(intent);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("photo", photoUri);
    picture picture = new picture();
    picture .setArguments(bundle);



}
```

It is fragment code

```
   String name = getArguments().getString("photo")
```

It is my logcat errors

```
11-23 13:57:04.667 12427-12427/com.example.test.namsan E/AndroidRuntime:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: com.example.test.namsan, PID: 12427   
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/com.example.test.namsan/IMG_20151123_135652.jpg }} to activity {com.example.test.namsan/com.example.test.namsan.CameraActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test.namsan/com.example.test.namsan.picture}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3394)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3437)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5129)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test.namsan/com.example.test.namsan.picture}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3468)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3429)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3671)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3639)
at com.example.test.namsan.CameraActivity.nextpageintent(CameraActivity.java:117)
at com.example.test.namsan.CameraActivity.onActivityResult(CameraActivity.java:93)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5467)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3437) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5129) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't declare camera fragment in manifest....

so i declare manifest camera framgent

and then it error fragment can't cast activity....

please help me..

Comment: **picture** is a fragment or activity?

Comment: It says `ActivityNotFoundException` which means you haven't declare  your activity in Manifest file

Comment: yes  but i can't declare manifest because it is not activity it is fragment

Comment: Your logcat says declare your class in the Manifest. May be you have forgotten to declare ur class in the Manifest.

Comment: @YoungjoonSon post your activity class and picture class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this way:

**Remove** below **two lines**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,picture.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now write whole below code:

**Set data** to **Fragment** as **Arguments**:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("photo", photoUri);
picture picture = new picture();
picture .setArguments(bundle);
```

**Replace fragment**:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, picture); 
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Your method looks like below:

```
private void nextpageintent(String photoUri){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("photo", photoUri);
    picture picture = new picture();
    picture .setArguments(bundle); 
    FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
    transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, picture); 
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! .  I try this code . it has error "transaction.replace(R.id.container, picture); "  what variable i put ()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void nextpageintent(String photoUri){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("photo", photoUri);
    picture picture = new picture();
    picture .setArguments(bundle);
}
```

Comment: @YoungjoonSon after above lines, try this 
`FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container, picture); 
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();`

Comment: Thank you for your comment . i try this and i wonder what variable put in transaction.add() i can't resolve symbol container

Comment: i have this line in main activity lay out "<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
"  and then R.id.container is OK but picture is error.... i can't understand why picture is error . picture is already fragment....

Comment: You need to take FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: @YoungjoonSon which type of fragment you are using, support or normal fragment?

Comment: I change FrameLayout and then i have another error " Wrong 2nd argument tyme. Found: 'com.example.test.namsan.picture', required: 'android.app.Fragment'  replace (int, android.app.Fragment) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applide to (int, com.example.test.namsan.picture)

Comment: then picture class should extend `Fragment`